# SQL join queries with no common key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query which gets a list of customers

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as customer_name, customer_email as customer_email FROM customers WHERE user_level = 'customer')
```

and for each of the rows I want to append this query

```
(SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as seller_name, seller_email FROM users WHERE user_level = 'seller')
```

For each customer, the seller would be the same as I have only one seller in my table so i want to get this output.  How can i create this?

```
customer_name    |     customer_email    |    seller_name    |     Seller_email
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
some customer    |   xxxxxxxxxxx         |    this seller    |    seller@email.com
some customer1   |   xxxxxxxxxxx         |    this seller    |    seller@email.com
some customer2   |   xxxxxxxxxxx         |    this seller    |    seller@email.com
```

Comment: Does MySQL have a CROSS JOIN?  That's what I would use in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only have a single record in your `users` table, you can use a `cross join` to get your desired results;

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as customer_name, 
       c.customer_email as customer_email,
       CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as seller_name, 
       u.seller_email 
FROM customers c cross join users u
WHERE c.user_level = 'customer'
      and u.user_level = 'seller'
```

Comment: I've never come across CROSS JOIN before and this does exactly what I was trying to do